# wp_insert_post always return blank page (but the post is created)

Tags: wordpress

I've try a lot of way to insert a post in WP with wp_insert_post but i've always the same problem.
When i try to insert a post the post is correctly insered but i obtain a blank page (page broken).
The last code i've used is this:

```
// Create post object
global $user_ID;
$new_post = array(
'post_title' => 'My New Post',
'post_content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...',
'post_status' => 'future',
'post_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
'post_author' => $user_ID,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_category' => array(0)
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

Comment: Usually a "Blank Page" refers to a PHP fatal error.
Please do the following:
1. Check the server error log files.
2. Set 'WP_DEBUG' to true in the wp-config.php file of WordPress.
And you should be able to spot the issue in the code.

Comment: This code is fine.Where you have used this code?  and which page  blank?

Comment: You're not showing enough code to reproduce the problem. Please, read the guide [ask].

Comment: I've created a plugin with only this code (as last try). @WisdmLabs: now i'll try.

Comment: @Bhumi Shah: this test plugin is executed on every page so every page goes into blank page

Comment: ok, with the WP_DEBUG enabled i've the following error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in()

Comment: So, i've found a solution here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-is_user_logged_in

Answer (score 0):

This could be a WordPress "Link URL" problem. You just need to select the File URL option to get the link to the image in the "Link URL" text box. There could be other reasons also. However, if it is "Link URL" problem it can be solved very easily. I followed the below blog to rectify the Link URL problem

http://scriptcrunch.com/2016/03/wordpress-insert-post-blank-page-issue.html